# how to avoid double quotes in a mongo query for regular expression

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am trying to find a mongo query in my server side, my query is like this

```
{
    $text: { $search: "beautiful" },
    "Category": {
        $elemMatch: {
            "title": { $in: [/Home/] }
        }
    },
    "Company": { $regex: /philips/i }
}
```

For the above query, I am getting the exact result I want but my problem is, Company name `"philips"` is from my html page to server side and in server side it tries to convert it like this `/philips/i` for the purpose of using this in query but it is taking as string in the mongo query.

**What I tried:**

```
var productCompany = philips; // <---(getting this from my html page)          
var productCmpnyRegex = '/' + productCompany + '/i'; 
query = {
    $text: { $search: "beautiful" },
    "Category": { 
        $elemMatch: {
            "title": { $in: [/Home/] }
        }
    },
    "Company": { $regex: productCmpnyRegex }
}
```

**What I expected:**

```
query = {
    $text: { $search: "beautiful" },
    "Category": {
        $elemMatch: { 
            "title": { $in: [/Home/] }
        }
    },
    "Company": { $regex: /philips/i }
}
```

but it is taking it as

```
query = {
    $text: { $search: "beautiful" },
    "Category": {
        $elemMatch: {
            "title": { $in: [/Home/] }
        }
    },
    "Company": { $regex: "/philips/i" }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap your regex pattern in the **[`RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)** constructor which creates a regular expression object for matching text with a pattern:

```
var productCmpnyRegex = new RegExp(philips, 'i'); // <-- creates a regex obj /philips/i;
query = {
    "$text": { "$search": "beautiful" },
    "Category": { 
        "$elemMatch": {
            "title": { "$in": [/Home/] }
        }
    },
    "Company": productCmpnyRegex
}
```